# How to define an exact sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $p$ be a prime. How to make an exact sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules (abelian groups):

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbb Z_p\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb Z_{p^2}\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb Z_{p^2}\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb Z_p\longrightarrow 0.$$

Since $\mathbb Z_{p}\subset \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ I thought taking $f$ as the inclusion. And I tried definying $h$ as: $$[a]_{p^2}\longmapsto [a]_p.$$ This is cleary surjective and its kernel is given by $p\mathbb Z_{p^2}$. The natural choice for $g$ would be $$[a]_{p^2}\longmapsto [pa]_{p^2}.$$
Then $\textrm{im}(g)=p\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ but it seems its kernel would also be $p\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ and not $\mathbb Z_p$ as desired.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: What do yo mean by «$\mathbb Z_p\subset\mathbb Z_{p^2}$» exactly?

Comment: I had in mind usual set theorical inclusion, but now that you asked I'm not sure if that makes sense..

Comment: In fact, there is not even a «usual set theoretical inclusion»!

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of what you suggested, take the sequence
$$0\longrightarrow p\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb Z/{p^2}\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} p\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow 0$$
with $g, h$ each multiplication by $p$.

Comment: Do you mean, $f$ and $g$ being multiplication by $p$? For if $f$ is the multiplication by $p$ then $\textrm{ker}(f)=\{[0]_p\}$ and $\textrm{im}(f)=p\mathbb Z_p$ and I'm almost sure $p\mathbb Z_{p^2}=p\mathbb Z_p$..

Comment: The first nonzero arrow above is the inclusion map. Also, $p(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, while $p(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})= 0$.

Comment: Agreed. Anyway, I guess I was indeed a bit unclear. I meant $f$ is the map $[a]_p\longmapsto [pa]_{p^2}$..